# Code not returning expected result

Tags: python

im trying to make a tiny text adventure game.

Why does this statement not return 90?

```
orc = raw_input("Does the orc attack or miss?")#Replacing with a random number thing later
health = 100

takeahit = 0

def damage(orc):
  if orc == "hit":
    return takeahit == 10 # Ive tried plus as well im having similar problems with choices in inventory
  elif orc == "miss":
    print "The Orc misses"

healthtwo = health - takeahit

print healthtwo
```

Answer (score 1):

Return from the function in an appropriate manner:

```
def damage(orc):
    print(orc)
    if orc == "hit":
        takeahit = 10 #MODIFIED
    elif orc == "miss":
        takeahit=0
        print "The Orc misses"
    return takeahit  #ADDED STATEMENT
```

You need to call the function defined.
Add this after the function definition

```
takeahit=damage(orc)
```